# XSLT Using doc function for xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am studying xml and XSLT.

and I would like to create XSLT file which can display all name from the family.xml file

I have...

> doc("family.xml")//NAME

However, I am not really sure syntax to use doc function on the XSLT file.

Does anyone can help me ?

thanks

Comment: how does your XSL look like right now?

Comment: What are you using to process the XSLT? That XPath you have could be executed as XQuery and return you exactly what you wanted without using XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your filename.xml is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

To get all the titles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">

<!-- match root documents tag -->
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('filename.xml')/bookstore//title/node()" mode="document"/>
</xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="/" mode="document">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why use `xsl:apply-templates` when you can just use the `xsl:copy-of` with the `document()` path in the select?

Comment: @Daniel: Just a preference as nothing was mentioned in the question..you can use copy-of or value-of or apply-templates etc. for this